# JSON_ENCODE no esta funcionando

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando obtener los valores de una consulta, la consulta como tal esta bien... ya que si intento retornar un indice del array, lo regresa perfectamente.. y en el success de mi peticion ajax lo reconoce perfectamente el problema es cuando trato de retornar todos los datos con json_encode...
A continuación mi codigo php

```
          function cargarDatos(){
            $baseDatos = new BD();
            if ($baseDatos->conBDPDO()) {
                
               
                $queryProductos = "select * from producto where estadoInmueble=1";
                $conn = $baseDatos->connBD->prepare($queryProductos);
                $conn ->execute();
                $arrayProductos =  $conn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $cont=0;
                
                echo json_encode($arrayProductos);
                
            }else{
                echo 'No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la base de datos';
            }
        }
```

Y Ahora mi petición Ajax

```
               $.ajax({
                url: "controladores/controlador_producto.php",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                success: (response) => {
                    
                    try {
                        arrayPropiedades = JSON.parse(response)
                        console.log(arrayPropiedades)
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    } 
                }
              });
```

en el success sale en blanco como si el array no tuviera nada y por consola tengo este error:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (producto.js:160)
    at c (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.send (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at producto.cargarDatos (producto.js:148)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:173)
```

Comment: ¿si haces un `console.log(response);`, antes del `parse`, obtienes la salida esperada?

Comment: Revisa en la consola del browser, en la pestaña Network, cuando se haga la llamada AJAX a tu controlador de PHP que es la respuesta que esta devolviendo, si hay un error en la ejecucion de PHP ahi se mostrara, abre el evento en la consola y busca el tab Response

Comment: Cuando utilizo var_dump si muestra el array.... `array(9) {[0]=>array(22) {["id"]=> string(2) "79"`

Comment: creo que el error está en el json_encode... @BetaM tienes alguna idea de que pueda ser?... lo raro es que local si me funcionaba..

Comment: @AugustoM me sale **this request has no response data avalaible**

Comment: utilicé `json_last_error()` y obtengo 5.. que hace referencia al error JSON_ERROR_UTF8... como podría corregirlo

Comment: Parece que estás teniendo problemas con la codificación. Establece `utf-8` en la conexión a la BD así como un `header` con codificación `utf-8` antes de enviar la respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano si amigo era eso exactamente, tuve que codificar cada registro devuelto de la bd con la ayuda de encode_utf-8.. muchas gracias..